# SQL Select columns by applying two conditions on the same column

Tags: sql

I want to return the column values by meeting two conditions on another column in SQL.

```
ORDER | STATUS
--------------
50    |  10
50    |  20
55    |  10
60    |  10
65    |  10
65    |  20
```

I want to return all orders if they have status = 10 and status != 20

Result:

```
ORDER
-----
 55
 60
```

I have tried the following code but it does not work:

```
Select Order 
FROM ordertable OT
where OT.STATUS in ('10') and OT.STATUS not in ('20')
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Thanks for your replies.  Let me clarify, I meant to return the entire row from table where orders have only status=10, not the order number only. I omitted the other columns in my example for clarity.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? It looks like jarlh answer is fine, but you might have to swap MINUS for EXCEPT.

Comment: `EXCEPT` is ANSI/ISO SQL (_Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL._)

Comment: @jarlh Yes, there's nothing wrong with your answer, but it still may not work for all databases. (Just double checked in Oracle to make sure I'm not losing my mind)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean????  "Doesn't work" will not help us help you.  No result???  Wrong result???  Query crashed????

Comment: If you want the whole row, why do you only `SELECT Order`???  Where's the rest of your column???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean this :

```
select order_ "Order"
  from ordertable ot
 where ot.status = 10
 minus 
select order_ "Order"
  from ordertable ot
 where ot.status = 20;
```

or this :

```
select order_ "Order"
  from ordertable ot
 where ( ot.status = 10 ) or ( ot.status != 10 and  ot.status = 20 ) 
 group by order_
having count(1)=1;
```

According to your last comment you want "return the entire row from table where orders have only status=10", then the following should suit best :

```
select order_ "Order"
  from ordertable ot
 group by order_
 having avg(ot.status)=10;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4491c/58) ( including three cases )

P.S. I don't know which DB are you running this SQL on, but `order` is a keyword and can not be used as a column name in any of them.

Comment: Hmm, this also returns orders with `status = 20` which have no other row with `status = 10`. I'm not sure if the OP wants that.

Comment: @stickybit you're right. I also couldn't understand exactly what he meant. With respect to the results, I thought so.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  Let me clarify, I meant to return the entire row from table where orders have only status=10, not the order number only.

Comment: @AdilMK you're welcome. I added the third case of the query according to your last comment. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXCEPT`

```
select order from ordertable where status = 10
except
select order from ordertable where status = 20
```

I.e. return order values having status 10, except those who have status 20.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where status = 10 and order not in (select order from table where status = 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is `group by` and `having`:

```
select order
from ordertable
where status in ('10', '20')
group by order
having max(status) = '10';
```

Comment: Gordon, I think you replied in a rush, check again please.